# use javascript return value in twig

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

I have dropdownlist that user can select one of it's option and then click a button to change a filed of that option in database
so i need a javascript return value to pass in a controller

for example this may be my code in *.html.twig:
** sign show where i need javascript function return value

```
{% block body %}
    <body>
        <div>
            <select id="ddl">
                {% for user in users %}
                <option >{{ user.username }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
            <button id="state" onclick="changeUserFilterState()"> filter state </button>
            <label  >{{**i need changeUserFilterState() return value here!!** }} </label>
            {% render controller('NEWSBlogBundle:Admin:admin' , { **and here!!** }) %}
        </div>
    </body>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twig is rendered and completed long before the client executes javascript.

You probably want to either redirect the user to a page and give the controller the request data it needs to give to twig, or perform an ajax request.

Comment: Not sure what your comments means.

Comment: thank you, that was helpful.
why ajax may help me (but not javascript)?

Comment: As I mentioned before, your only option if you want Twig to render with a given set is to initialize a new HTTP request using the url to transport your data, i.e., /my/path/?option=foobar). Your controller will then have the data available as a part of the Request, and you can either render the appropriate template from the controller, or pass the data to twig and allow it to render a sub template.